# Is it necessary to validate htaccess variables output

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is it necessary to validate what come in from htaccess rules?

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]{4})/?$ /run/run.php?year=$1 [NC,L]
This does http://www.localhost/2014
```

In this case, I've written the htaccess rule to allow only 4 digits. Is it necessary for me to do:

```
$thisYear = $_GET['year'];
```

and check if it's numeric etc. Will alphabets get through?

Comment: There is a saying that a good programming is one that looks both ways when crossing a one way street. I would advise to still do validation but it just constitutes a "this should never happen" condition.

Answer (score 2):

The key is separation of responsibilities.

Your rewrite rules are meant to direct input to your application, nothing more.  Your application is responsible for determining what is valid, and what isn't.

While it is true that you will only get 4 digits from the rewrite rule you have shown, is `run.php` accessible directly?  What happens if someone were to find it?

In more general cases where you accept broader input for rewrite, but more specific rules for processing, you don't want to have to change your rewrite rules every time your application needs change.

Comment: run.php is not accessible directly. It is not the index file either.

Comment: it isn't possible that in the future you make the `run.php` file available directly, or directing input to it from another place? I would still check there that the input is correct. Also, this `RewriteRule` would redirect if the year is `9999` or `0000`. Is this a valid year for your application?

Comment: It is not, but it'll return no results. `select * from table where year = 9999`